# Object #<Screen> has no method 'updateMatrixWorld' ERROR

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im trying to create sun, but when I test run this code I get error

```
THREE.CanvasRenderer 54 three.min.js:262
102
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Screen> has no method 'updateMatrixWorld' three.min.js:126
192
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Screen> has no method 'updateMatrixWorld'
```

And I'm using latest build too, i downloaded yesterday (12th Jan 2013) only.

Please help me find what I'm doing wrong !

Also, would like to know difference btw WebGLRenderer and CanvasRenderer.

```
   <script src="vendor/three.js/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/three.js/Detector.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/three.js/ShaderExtras.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/three.js/Stats.js"></script>
<script>
    var scene, renderer, camera, container, W, H;

    W = parseInt(document.body.clientWidth);
    H = parseInt(document.body.clientHeight);

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, W / H, 1, 10000); //field of view, aspect ratio, near and far clipping plane
    camera.position.z = 4300;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    //Sun
    var sun, sun_geom, sun_mat;
    sun_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(430, 30, 30); //radius, second and third parameters how many triangles to generate
    sun_mat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    sun = new THREE.Mesh(sun_geom, sun_mat);
    scene.add(sun);

    //renderer
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(W, H);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    animate();

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        renderer.render(screen, camera);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the animate function

Fixed the line `renderer.render(scene,camera);`

Im sorry for posting such a silly quesion, silly misstakes :|